# Nginx: Setting a default file extension

Tags: nginx

What rule would I use for nginx so my default file extension is .php?

I currently access a pages using  www.mywebsite.com/**home.php** but I want to just use www.mywebsite.com/**home**

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you also want to serve static files, you could use something like this:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  # Set the docroot directly in the server
  root /var/www;

  # Allow index.php or index.html as directory index files
  index index.html index.php;

  # See if a file or directory was requested first.  If not, try the request as a php file.
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # If the php file doesn't exist, don't pass the request to php, just return a 404
    try_files $uri =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

    fastcgi_pass your_php_backend_address;
  }
}
```

Comment: to pass parameters ?$args must be included. I mean try_files line should be : try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;

Comment: the ``try_files $uri =404;`` was causing every request to 404 for me with nginx v1.4.1, but otherwise the ``try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php?$args;`` is great.