# Remove file extension from url nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, backend, nginx-config

I want to remove file extension from url and somehow I am succeded.

whenever I visit /xyz.html page it redirects to /xyz but throws 404 error.

```
server {
listen      172.31.86.864:80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.error.log error;


location / {
    proxy_pass      http://172.31.86.864:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html$) {
    return 302 /$1;
}
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;

}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/domain.com/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://142.15.217.244:8080;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}
```

include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.domain.com.conf*;
}

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970674/remove-php-file-extension-with-nginx-php-fpm/17475222

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work (took the code from https://serverfault.com/questions/346994/hide-html-file-extensions-using-nginx-rewrites)

```
try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I figured out it myself. I made changes to the Apache2.conf file.

Comment: Feel free to do what ever you want.