# Removing index extension in nginx

Tags: nginx

With Apache the directive `DirectoryIndex index` along with `DefaultType application/x-httpd-php` within a particular vhost worked quite well to exclude a file extension from index files without rewriting.  How can I duplicate this in Nginx?  So far all I've been able to find is regex rewriting solutions.

Comment: Your question has been answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760883/nginx-setting-a-default-file-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760883/nginx-setting-a-default-file-extension)

Comment: Close, but no, it doesn't.  That solution would require that the file be named index.php.  I'm looking to remove the extension from the front-end AND the back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .conf file would look something like this:

```
server {
server_name example.com;

# Set the docroot directly in the server
root /var/www;

    # Allow index.php or index.html as directory index files
    index index;

    # See if a file or directory was requested first.  If not, try the request as a php file.
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

the line `try_files $uri` should try the files without extensions on the backend